# How many different paths can the ball take as it falls from top to bottom?

Tags: combinatorics

**How many different paths can the ball take as it falls from top to bottom?**

I've shown my work below; I am wanting to make sure that I've applied Pascal's Triangle to this shape correctly. Honestly, I'm not too familiar with this kind of problem, so I just need to know–

**Is this correct, or am I completely on the wrong track?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bottom rightmost $5$ should be a $6$, giving $126$ paths instead of $125$. Otherwise, your work is correct.

An easier way would be to just compute ${9\choose 4}$ directly. (Can you see why?)

Comment: Corrected, thank-you. I'm afraid I don't see why.. Do you mind giving a brief explanation?

Comment: I mean, the third row from the bottom should read 15-20-15-6 instead of 15-20-15-5, since the two numbers above the 6 are "1" and "5".

Comment: Sorry, I saw why the 5 needed to be replaced with a 6.. I meant about the 9,4 notation you mentioned. What does that mean, and how did you know that would give me the same answer?

Comment: rotating the image slightly may make the problem seem a little more familiar :)

Comment: Oh. Well, every path requires 5 movements southeast and 4 movements southwest in order to reach the bottom-most point. How many ways can you order EEEEEWWWW?

Comment: Ah, I see. Makes sense. So you cam move any combo of 5E and 4W to get to the bottom-most point. Do you mind explaining what the (9/4) means? Or how I would get 126 from that?

Comment: It's a binomial coefficient, basically encrypted within the rows of  Pascal's triangle. ${9\choose 4}=\frac{9!}{4!\times 5!}=\frac{9\times8\times7\times\cdots \times 1}{(4\times 3\times\cdots\times 1)\times (5\times 4\times \cdots \times 1)}$

Comment: Thanks, I had never seen that before.

Comment: I asked a similar question here, but I am unsure of even where to start. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1065811/find-the-number-of-pathways-from-a-to-b-if-you-can-only-travel-to-the-right-and